Understanding sealed traits in Rust
I am trying to create a mock object for testing in my Rust project. I am having an issue where I would like to implement a generic trait the type parameter of which must also implement another trait. The compiler is telling me that the generic trait is 'sealed'.
Here is a minimally reproducible example:
pub trait Trait {

    fn trait_test_function();
}

pub trait TraitWithBound<T: Trait> {

    fn trait_with_bound_test_function();
}

pub struct StructPassedAsGeneric {

}

pub struct TestStruct {


}

impl Trait for StructPassedAsGeneric {

    fn trait_test_function() {
        
    }
}

impl<StructPassedAsGeneric> TraitWithBound<StructPassedAsGeneric> for TestStruct {

    fn trait_with_bound_test_function() {
        
    }
}

The error says that:
the trait bound `StructPassedAsGeneric: Trait` is not satisfied
`TraitWithBound` is a "sealed trait", because to implement it you also need to implement `tests::component_tests::graph::commands::teststest::Trait`, which is not accessible; this is usually done to force you to use one of the provided types that already implement it
the following type implements the trait:
  tests::component_tests::graph::commands::teststest::StructPassedAsGeneric

I dont quite understand what is meant by a sealed trait, the trait TraitWithBound is public, and my StructPassedAsGeneric implements Trait.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? The error seems to hint that there may be a different FileDescriptor you need to implement, but I'm not sure.

@kmdreko have edited to simplify

The code produces a different, unrelated error which can be fixed by a trait bound: impl<StructPassedAsGeneric: Trait> TraitWithBound please provide a [mre] wich produces the error you claim.

A sealed trait is one like the compiler says: it has an inaccessible supertrait, so you cannot implement it.  You'd create such a trait like this:
mod example {
    trait Private {}

    pub trait Sealed: Private {}
}

struct Type;

impl example::Sealed for Type {}

This yields the same error as in your question.  In this example, Sealed is the sealed trait.  Note that it has Private as a supertrait, but that trait is not visible from outside of the example module.  Therefore, the trait example::Sealed cannot be implemented anywhere that example::Private is not visible, because implementing the former also requires implementing the latter.
This is commonly used, as the compiler error says, to prevent other crates/modules from implementing a trait, perhaps because the trait contains "private" implementation details of the crate, but must still be public.
